# how to delete a specific data from a list of data in ionic 3 real time Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I was able to upload and fetch data but i want to use a button to delete a data from a list of data.
below is my code

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PagesAllpatientsPage');
    this.ph.getPatientProfile(this.id).once('value', snapshot => {
      this.patientsList = [];
      console.log('sjiy')
      snapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.patientsList.push({
          id: snap.key,
         name: snap.val().name,
         age: snap.val().age,
         gender: snap.val().gender,
         phonenumber: snap.val().phonenumber,
        });
        console.log(this.patientsList)
        return false
      });
    });

  }

  deletePatient(id:any,) {
    firebase.database().ref(`userProfile/${this.user.uid}/PatientInfo/${id}`).remove(id)
  }
```

All i want to achieve is to remove a data from patientInfo with a button click and please also provide [image]

```
<button ion-button block (click)="deletePatient(id)">Delete Record</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but it might help someone in need.

```
/* this will help you get the ref of unique id of the current data */
uid = **apH....q1e2** in this case
let ref = this.afDatabase.database.ref('userProfile/' + uid + 'PatientInfo');
    
/* now to remove patient info */
ref.remove().then(data => {
console.log('Data removed successfully.');
})
```